# Understanding an implication involving symetric groups, alternating groups, and normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand the following statement:

Let's suppose that $\forall n, H \triangleleft A_n$ contains a $3$-cycle.

$A_n \triangleleft S_n$ has and index of $2$.

If  $(abc) \in H \implies \exists (de) \in S_n/A_n$ s.t  $(de)$ and $(abc)$ are disjoint and s.t. $(abc)(de) = (de)(abc)$

**Here's what I don't understand**

1. Why does there exist $(ed) \in S_n/A_n$?
2. Why are $(de)$ and $(abc)$ disjoint?
3. Why do they commute?

Comment: Please correct the 2nd line.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Done! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

The mapping $S_n\rightarrow\{\pm 1\}:\pi\mapsto {\rm sgn}(\pi)$ is a group homomorphism, surjective if $n\geq 2$. The kernel is $A_n$ and so $A_n$ has index 2 in $S_n$.

Comment: How does that imply that 1. there exist $(ed) \in S_n/A_n$?
 2.  $(de)$ and $(abc)$ are disjoint?
 3. They commute?